# .net 6.0 Set description for extension .UseWindowsService()

Tags: c#, windows-services, worker-service

I would like to know if is there any way to set the description in a service directly in the code?

The app is a worker service console .net 6.0 and I'm using the extension for windows services and using it with: `.UseWindowsService()`
I checked some websites but didn't found anything, the last one I checked was: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/self-hosted

Anyone know if it is possible to set the description, display name and service name?

In the code I didn't tryed anything because I could not really find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you may have missed from the [article you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/self-hosted) happens to be the point where you would set the Service Name, Display, and Description:

> .. Then, use the sc tool to create a Windows service for the executable file.
>
> `sc create MyService binPath=C:\MyService\MyService.exe`

Referring to the doco for [sc create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create) and [sc description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc742069(v=ws.11)), you'll need to issue both commands:

```
sc create MyServiceName binPath="C:\MyService.exe" displayName="My displayname"
sc description MyServiceName "My description"
```

(I have no idea why they couldn't embed the description into `sc create`)

Comment: That kind of helped! So I think it's impossible to permanently set it in the code, I will always have to use a command to put it.
I'll mark your answer as correct because it helped me and I can now set the description after creating the service. Thanks @NPras.